# Can browser change HTML?

Tags: html, browser, gulp

My mark up looks like this

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a class="link-to-product" href="#">
        <div class="stickers">
            <div class="sticker discounts">Акции</div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-top">
            <div class="img-wrap"><img src="img/box2.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="category">Жидкости</div>
            <div class="title">Масло черного тмина</div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-down">
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="price-container">
                <div class="current-price">
                    <span>250 </span>
                    <span class="currency">грн.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="old-price">
                    <span>300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="buy-button" href="#">Купить</a>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is what I see in browser devtools:

[image]

`.thumbnail-down` falls out of `.link-to-product`.

I tried different browsers (chrome, firefox), cleared cache, turned of css and js. And still `.thumbnail-down` falls out of `.link-to-product`.

I wrote the mark up in `pug` and compiled html with `gulp`. When i look at compiled `html` in `dist` folder it looks alright. I actually copied sample of code out from this file. Holy cow. What can cause such weird behavior?

I checked all links before this element and after. they are all properly closed

Not only it falls out. Browser copies `.link-to-product`. There is no css and js on this page, just pure html. And I copied it to different folder with no gulp and no other plugins

[image]

Comment: Yes, since your HTML is invalid, most browsers will attempt to fix it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was caused by a simple typographical error, would be impossible to reproduce without making that typographical error again, and didn't produce any error codes that could be searched for in case someone else has this happen. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  for why this question is off-topic for these reasons.

Comment: It's not a typographical error. I need .link-to-product to move to products page, and "buy-button" to add product to cart without visiting it's page. Usualy programer puts void() inside link and uses it to call some wp or opencart "add to cart" actions. So yes, i placed link in link, but there was div divider between them. Or is it typographical error? If it is, i will delete question, no problem

Comment: Oh and i cant delete it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without nesting a inside a.

What I mean is

```
<a class="buy-button" href="#">Купить</a>
```

is inside

```
<a class="link-to-product" href="#">
```

My guess is that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: Yep, that's what causing the problem. I tried to wrap `.buy-button` into div. Didn't help much. Guess i'll have to use js for button. Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to wrap an `<a>` around an `<a>`. Does the `<a class="link-to-product" href="#">` has to go to the same url than `<a class="buy-button" href="#">Купить</a>` ? If yes, replace `<a class="buy-button" href="#">Купить</a>` to `<span class="buy-button">Купить</span>`

Comment: Since the whole thing is a link, I think you should take any buttons and links out of it. I think it's better for browser compatibility and for user experience.